# What is string frequency

Tags: java

Write a java code to check if the given string is even or not? Eg. aabbcc, aacbbc is even string.

I was asked this program in one interview. Actually i did not understand what is frequency here.

Comment: I think "frequency" just means the count of the number of times a letter appears.

Comment: Don't you have examples of correct answers?

Comment: Are you looking for an answer or an explanation?

Comment: Personally, I think that "eveness" occurs when all the characters appear the same number of times. But I can't be sure about this.

Comment: What is an odd String? "omo"? What about "lomo"? How is this related to frequency? Frequency of the set of characters in the string?

Comment: @RafaelPaulino they given that aabbcc, aacbbc are the example of even string.

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui explanation might be helpful for me. As I said I didn’t understand it clearly that’s why i was unable to code it.

Comment: Still not clear. What is being called EVEN STRING? It could be: all the letters in the string have the same count? or, all the counts of letters in the string are even?

Comment: @RafaelPaulino I had the same two perceptions in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

For a string `s` of length `n`, consider `s[0] XOR s[1] ... XOR s[n - 1]` where `[i]` is the (`i`)th letter of the string. Use `java.lang.String#charAt(int)` in java to extract a character.

If that is zero you have an even string, else you have an odd string.

Test `n % 2` first for an immediate pay rise: If that is not zero then there must be at least 1 occurrence of a character that appears an odd number of times.

Normally folk who wrote computer games in machine code as kids in the 1980s will ask this question as it seems obvious to them. I doubt it is any more: `XOR` was a very fast way of writing sprite images.

Comment: It’s not about the string length I think. If i am right it was related to character occurrence.

Comment: @Er.Amol Indeed, it's not about the string length. It's about whether or not each character in the string appears an even number of times. But that definition of evenness is only attained if the number of total characters is even.

Comment: Agree. But then we further have to test for the character occurrence. Right?

Comment: @Er.Amol Of course. The initial length check I'm proposing saves you evaluating the XOR case for a population of stings when the result is already known.

Comment: so if string length is even the we have to count occurrence of each character and then if all character are appeared even number of times then string will be even. Right?

Comment: @Er.Amol: Did you read my answer? I showed you how to do it.

Comment: How the code for this would look like?

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what the interviewer was asking, string frequency is either,

1. how many times a string is found in another string.
2. how many times a character is found in a string.

Comment: But they said method will accept a string as argument and will check for even or not. So the option second is correct.

Comment: They want the string to be passed into the function, then the function returns if the number of times a character shows up is even or odd, right?

Comment: yes but they are not giving specific character they just gave string.

Comment: hmm then it seems like they want whether or not the frequency of every character in the string is even or odd.

Comment: I think all the character in string are of same count then the string will be even and odd in all other cases.

Comment: That is a very good assumption. +1